# Continually reorder a range's ID sequence as users cut/paste rows

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Visual of needed ordering]

Please see the attached image to see how I need to keep the basic order of row identifiers within the larger sheet. Over time, users will add and delete rows or move rows up or down within each 'section' to denote relative importance. These rows, where inserted or moved to, will take the letter ID in order within the section, not take their previous ID with them. As changes are made, the need is for a VBA script to execute reordering the letter row identifiers to alphabetical A-Z.

No code to show where I'm stuck at as I'm not even sure what the trigger will be. Basic structure advice would be as appreciated as any specific code to try.

Comment: For any who can't see the attached image (my company's firewall blocks it), the row order within column "A" I talk about looks like this:  Section 1, a, b, c, d, etc., Section 2, a, b, c, d, e, f, etc..., Section 3, a.....etc.

Comment: And no, I didn't come up with the ordering. It's an existing sheet I've been asked to improve and automate in specific ways, including this one.  Thanks again for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-vba solution that may work or get you close:

Use this formula in each cell where there is a letter:

```
=CHAR(ROW()-MATCH("Section "&COUNTIF($A$2:A3,"Section*"),$A$1:$A3,0)+96)
```

Each time a user performs cut / copy and paste it will work. If they enter a new line altogether they can copy the formula from another row.

Explanation Follows:

- `COUNTIF($A$2:A3,"Section*")` = count the sections to determine which section any given row belongs to
- `MATCH("Section "& ... COUNTIF ..., $A$1:$A3,0)` = find the row where the section begins in the dataset
- `CHAR(ROW()- ... MATCH ... + 96)` = subtract current row from section begin row and add 64 to convert number order to ascii characters starting from (a,b,c,d,e)

Comment: Your solution is very elegant and I tried a formula solution before (not as good as yours). I have to keep in mind the users' level of Excel expertise (some to none). Enforcing a 'copy the formula when adding new rows' rule won't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @QFarley - if you can't ask your users to copy a formula only that says a lot. Alternatively, you can probably program VBA code to do it for them when a row is added.